# In Emacs, how can I enable a minor mode unless another is active?

Tags: emacs

I am trying to use both minimap and fill-column-indicator modes in emacs, with fci-mode enabled for all buffers *but* the minimap.

I've adapted code from [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849467), and made this for my .emacs file :

```
(require 'fill-column-indicator)
(require 'minimap)                   
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-fci-mode fci-mode
  (lambda ()
    (unless minimap-mode
      (fci-mode))))
(my-global-fci-mode 1)
```

With this code, fci-mode gets enabled in all buffers, including the minimap one. Why?

Comment: For readers who are interested in knowing more about fci-mode, here is the link to the Github site for Al Parker:  https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator

Comment: My best guess is that `fci-mode` activates as soon as the minimap buffer is created, and before the function `minimap-create` has a chance to finish.  The function `minimap-create` calls a helper function `minimap-new-minimap`, which contains `(minimap-mode 1)`.  Therefore, `fci-mode` is active in the minimap buffer because your `lambda` function has already been run once when the minimap buffer was first created.  My suggestion would be to create a new function for `minimap-create` and put `(fci-mode 0)` at the bottom of it.

Comment: What @lawlist says sounds like it might well explain the behavior. But before trying to work around the problem, I'd suggest adding some debug info (via `message` or even `debug`), to confirm the problem or understand it better. Once you know just what is happening you can think about how to fix it, based on that knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I added a `message` command as @Drew suggested and saw that `minimap-mode = nil` when the lambda function is called. @lawlist, would I create the new `minimap-create` function in my `.emacs` file? Thanks.